# How to make tabs that change the info on the screen

Tags: html

I am making a web page, and I want there to be tabs like on this page

http://wistia.com/pricing where it changes the price from monthly to annual when clicked.

How would I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery UI's Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) is one option for you. Otherwise you could roll your own using a combination of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they use something like `div` and *Jquery*

Might be usefull : [Jquery tutorial](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers)